# Use Enterprise Security API Java to encode arabic text

Tags: java, encoding, arabic, esapi

Im using ESAPI to avoid XSS, so I need to validate all inputs and encode all Outputs.

Im using ESAPI in Java using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And Im using the following code to validate and encode output:

1- Validate inputs:

```
 if(!ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("Form Data",input ,"SafeString", 300, true)) {
           throw new ValidationException("this data has XSS code", "this data has XSS code");
           }
```

which works just fine to detect any malicious code, let me know if there is something better than this.

2- encode output:

```
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute("<script>التا");
```

The expected output of this encoding should be:

```
&lt;script&gt;التا
```

but its actually:

```
&lt;script&gt;&#x627;&#x644;&#x62a;&#x627;
```

so how to make ESAPI returns what I'm expecting?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: There’s a 2.0.1.2 release that I think will address this.  The original implementation destroyed character sets above a certain range.  I’d have that info here but I fixed it last year.  Do me a favor and pull the latest develop branch and drop it in your app.  I bet it works...

Comment: Thanks @avgvstvs, but how can I pull that branch? link plz?

Comment: Clone the main ESAPI-java-legacy develop branch and drop it in your project.  It’s on github.  Esapi/ESAPI-java-legacy

Comment: but unfortunately the company cant use code from GIt hub due to some policy, any other way out plz?

Comment: That doesn’t stop you from testing it to see if it works.  You don’t need a full release from us for that.

Comment: And keep in mind if you’re already using ESAPI you’re alread using “code from github”

Comment: uh okay, so how can I get it as a jar file so I can just add it to my lib

Comment: I never cloned something from GitHub to use it in my project so I'll be needing ur help on that, hoping if it works I can just drop its dependency into my POM

Comment: https://github.com/esapi/esapi-java-legacy/

Comment: Then just open a command prompt:  ‘git Clone https://github.com/esapi/esapi-java-legacy/“ and you get your jarfile by “mvn install”.